# EMF produced when a square wire is pulled from the corners

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, induction

The shown diagram is of a square conducting frame being pulled from the corners. The velocity of A and B is given as $u$. Each side has length $a$. I was trying to find the induced emf at the instant when $\theta = 60°$. B is given.

$$\phi =\int B.dS \;\;\tag{1}$$ $$ \text{emf} = \frac{d\phi}{dt} \;\; \tag{2}$$  where $$\begin{align} \phi = \text{ the flux},\\ B =\text{magnetic field}, \\ S= \text{area covered}.  \end{align}$$

So, I tried finding the change in area($dS$) with respect to time (which is a very complex thing) and through $\text{emf}= \dfrac{d(\int B.dS)}{dt}$ found emf(which is quite complex). But the answer is too simple and I believe there may be a different way of doing this(an easier and smarter way). Does anybody have any idea how?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: sorry, its not even near to homework. Its a doubt based on a different question @JohnRennie

Comment: What don't you like about simple answers? There is a generation of string theorists out there who would do anything to get even one simple answer out of the formalism.

Comment: umm, i am not getting that simple answer with his method@CuriousOne

Comment: At theta (I'd use beta (b) here) radians the area would be. 4 x 1/2.a.Cos b/2.Sin b/2...then we have area =a.Sinb. And the rest is predictable

Comment: yes, but u have to write the angles(a,b) in terms of time, so that you can differentiate wrt time :d(∫B.dS)/dt. That makes it complex later on @slhulk

Comment: The emf is not constant right?

Comment: True, that's why we integrate @slhulk

Comment: i have answered the question, u can see @slhulk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody who have tried to answer my question. After working all night, I finally got it correct. I did it in the following manner:

Area covered by the rhombus at any point of time = $a^2 sin \theta$

$\frac{d(a cos(\theta/2))}{dt}$ = $u$

$\frac{-a sin(\theta/2)}{2} \times \frac{d\theta}{dt} = u$

$ϕ = B a^2 sin \theta$

$\frac{dϕ}{dt} = - Ba^2 cos\theta \frac{d\theta}{dt}$

You put the value of $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ in terms of $u$ and get the emf as $2Bau \frac{cos\theta}{sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}$ where $\theta$=60° and that's the answer.

Comment: :) u figured it out.